# путь до папки Downloads

Tags: java, android

Друзья, есть такой момент. Мне нужно узнать путь до папки `Downloads`, если есть флешка то флешки, если нет то памяти телефона.

Папку `Downloads` с флешки я беру таким кодом:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

Но на Sony Z2, этот метод не работает и думаю есть много телефонов где этот метод не работает. (на Sony Z2 флешка стояла).

Но, если нет флешки как получить путь `Downloads` на памяти телефона?

Мне нужно скачать PDF файл в эту директорию, если скачиваю в другое место, то PDF Reader, не может открыть этот файл, хотя я проверяю директорию на `.canRead` и `.canWrite`

В интернете есть много решений с определением флешки на разных телефонах, но нормальное решение не нашел.

Comment: Вы в правильном направлении, всё что вам осталось - , это проверять существует ли dir, если нет то создавать и записывать, если да, то просто записывать, по моему - очевидно. Тот код который вы указали это просто запрос у среды для формирования стандартного пути к папке download для внешнего носителя и не более чем.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei а как сделать запрос к папке Download не внешнего носителя, а внутреннего?